# Rotate animations with speed, direction and if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

i have only vertically mouse following menu  div. i was using flash before to animate it but now i have it in js code. only part missing is the wheels rotating animation as div moves. 
there will be 2 wheels rotating different ways like

`wheel 1 rotate - , wheel 2 rotate + direction when mouse Y < div Y and wheel 1 + , wheel 2 - for mouse Y > div Y.`

i dont have if statement for both situations but its the easier part for me if we can insert a rotate function inside the if statement below just for 1 situation. and about rotate speed it was equal to div movement speed `yp += (mouseY - yp) / 10;`  in flash so it was gettin slower or faster  but dont know if we can make it in js. thank you for your help

```
var  mouseY = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
mouseX = e.pageX;
mouseY = e.pageY; 
});


var follower = $("#follower");
var follower_2 = $("#follower_2");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function()

{if((mouseY - yp >200 || yp - mouseY >250)||(( mouseX - xp >530 || mouseX - xp <280)&&(  mouseX - xp <1370 || mouseX - xp >1620) )){






yp += (mouseY - yp) / 10;
follower.css({ top:yp-200});
follower_2.css({ top:yp-565});
}}, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is that you need to add 'px' to the end of your css statement like this:

```
follower.css({ top:yp-200 + 'px'});
follower_2.css({ top:yp-565 + 'px'});
```

Comment: It was working already but thanks for the tip i ve added it to code. And in IE code is not working at start but after refreshing page 2-3 times. Any idea?

Comment: try putting `$(window).load(function() {//code});` around your code

Comment: Perfect! i saw so many titles about it but no answer really. refresh commands onload etc. i am creatin a new question for this only.. if you can write this answer to there i ll be happy to set it as accepted answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440876/in-ie-some-of-the-js-jquery-codes-are-not-working-at-start-but-after-refreshing waiting for your answer to accept.