# In IE Some of the JS, Jquery codes are not working at start but after refreshing page 2-3 times. Any idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In IE Some of the  JS, Jquery codes  are not working at start but after refreshing page 2-3 times. Any idea?  here is my code :

```
var  mouseY = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
mouseX = e.pageX;
mouseY = e.pageY; 
});


var follower = $("#follower");
var follower_2 = $("#follower_2");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function()

{if((mouseY - yp >200 || yp - mouseY >250)||(( mouseX - xp >530 || mouseX - xp <280)&&( mouseX - xp <1370 || mouseX - xp >1620) )){






yp += (mouseY - yp) / 10;
follower.css({ top:yp-200 + 'px'});
follower_2.css({ top:yp-565 + 'px'});
}}, 25);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside : `$().ready()` function and make your `mouseX` global varibale.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var  mouseY = 0,mouseX=0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
mouseX = e.pageX;
 mouseY = e.pageY; 
});


 var follower = $("#follower");
 var follower_2 = $("#follower_2");
 var xp = 0, yp = 0;
 var loop = setInterval(function()

 {if((mouseY - yp >200 || yp - mouseY >250)||(( mouseX - xp >530 || mouseX - xp <280)&&( mouseX - xp <1370 || mouseX - xp >1620) )){


yp += (mouseY - yp) / 10;
 follower.css({ top:yp-200 + 'px'});
 follower_2.css({ top:yp-565 + 'px'});
 }}, 25);

 });

 })
```

Provide your fiddle for better answering.

May this helps you..

Comment: Thanks. But not working. @Hive7 already solved this problem in my other question about this script. $(window).load(function() {//code});  waiting for his answer to accept.

Comment: Are you able to provide me your fiddle ,so i can check ,on my side?

Comment: This is the script im using. Not same but same error.http://jsfiddle.net/88526/1/

Comment: Which version of IE you used?

Comment: your above script contains error,like mouseX is undefind,because it is not global var.